# The random code i generate does not increment by one on page load instead it chooses any value

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using the code below i am able to generate a random last digit code, however i want it to increment by 1 on page load.

The input field it should show in an element.

```js
function agentId() {
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  var acode = 'GA000444x'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    d = Math.floor(d / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
  });
  document.getElementById('acode').innerHTML = acode;
}

window.onload = function() {
  agentId();
};
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label for="acode">Agent Code:</label>
  <button type="button" id="acode"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: store you code in [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: @vanowm would you mind modifying the same and post it here please?

Comment: How are you suppose to increase by 1? It's an agent code. What base is that?

Comment: okay for instance when i load the page it shows GA0004442, then when i load once again it shows GA0004446, note the last digit, it does not increase by 1 instead it chooses a random digit, so i want when i load it generates GA0004441, when i load again it generates GA0004442 and so on...i hope you understand @IT goldman

Comment: How should it increment by one if you assign a random number on each invocation? Also: your code suggests that just the last digit should be changed - from 1-9 back to 0? Lastly: the preceeding `GA000444` is static?

Comment: One of your classmates asked this question already

Answer (score 0):

As implied in the comments, you should use `localStorage` to store values for later.

Note: snippets here don't allow for localStorage access so test this code some where else.

```js
function increase() {
  agentId(++last_digit)
  try {
    localStorage.setItem(last_digit)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

function agentId(last_digit) {
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  var acode = 'GA000444x'.replace(/[xy]/g, last_digit);
  document.getElementById('acode').innerHTML = acode;
}

var last_digit

window.onload = function() {
  try {
    last_digit = localStorage.getItem("last_digit") || 0;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    last_digit = 1;
  }
  agentId(last_digit);
};
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label for="acode">Agent Code:</label>
  <button type="button" id="acode" onclick="increase()"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: i appreciate for the attempt i have run the code and it returns GA0004440 which is okay, however if i load the page for it to generate a new code which is GA0004441, there are no changes to the code...

Comment: @VINCENTJEDI If you reload the page, your new code is random EVERYTIME, how do you expect the last digit to increment for example 4 to 5 on a reload if it's random for example 8 to 3...?

Comment: @zer00ne am getting your point but now in this case it is a specific code GA0004440 and the last value should increase by 1 everytime the page is loaded to give a new agentcode...say GA0004441